# Issues in Cross compiling when linking GMP to GCC

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, gmp

Using the [How To Build GCC 4.8.2 ARM Cross-Compiler](https://how-to-build-for-arm.wikispaces.com/gcc-4_8_2), I have installed and setup everything and it works just fine as mentioned in the post i.e., I was able to cross compile a simple C code. But, when I try to compile a simple GMP code, I get this error.

```
fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory 
Compilation terminated
```

How should I fix this? My goal is to compile a gmp program. If possible, refer me to good tutorials.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want GMP compiled for the target system (ARM), you must compile it by itself using the newly built cross-compiler, **not as a part of building GCC**. GMP (along with MPFR, MPC, ISL, CLooG, etc.) being placed in the GCC toplevel source directory simply means that it gets compiled and linked for the cross-compiler you're building.

Since the cross-compiler will run on the host system, GMP will also be compiled for the host system, else linking the library would fail, and you wouldn't get a cross-compiler. It may sound silly, but there are reasons for doing it this way, such as buggy prebuilt packages provided by the package manager on the host system or merely to avoid installing those libraries on the host system when all you want is the cross-compilation toolchain.

Comment: I have tried compiling GMP but am facing some errors. Could you see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798560/linking-problems-for-gmp-to-gcc-during-cross-compilation) and explain how to overcome it?